# skaknew package, double check symbol

Tags: fontsize, chess

I've written some 'beginners guide' to chess using LaTeX.

With following preamble:

```
  \usepackage[skaknew]{chessboard,skak}
```

And the following code:

```
 \par ...laten. Er volgt
 \mainline{1... Nf2+ 2. Kg1 Nh3+}{\scriptsize$\boldsymbol{+}$}\textbf{!} (dubbelschaak) 
 \mainline{3. Kh1 Qg1+!} (een dameoffer!) 
 \mainline{4. Rxg1 Nf2\mate}
```

Which results in:
[image: chess]

But the double check ++ seems off. The symbol isn't recognized by skaknew so I tried typing adjusting it, but I don't seem to get there. Could anyone help?

#### MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[skaknew]{chessboard,skak}

\begin{document}
\newgame
\par \mainline{1. Kh1} 

\par ...laten. Er volgt
\mainline{1... Nf2+ 2. Kg1 Nh3+}{\scriptsize$\boldsymbol{+}$}\textbf{!} (dubbelschaak) 
\mainline{3. Kh1 Qg1+!} (een dameoffer!) 
\mainline{4. Rxg1 Nf2\mate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The check symbol is called `\checksymbol`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, this solves the issue perfectly! If you would turn this into an answer I would gladly accept it.

Comment: @dietervdf I can't produce a working version, so a MWE is still needed

Comment: @egreg added a MWE

Comment: @dietervdf Which doesn't compile: `! mainline: white, not black, to move (Nf2+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably makes no sense for real chess moves, but it should give the idea; the check symbol is called `\checksymbol`, so you can get away with

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[skaknew]{chessboard,skak}

\begin{document}
\newgame

\par ...laten. Er volgt
\mainline{1. Kg1 Nh3+\checksymbol!} (dubbelschaak)
\mainline{2. Kh1 Qg1+!} (een dameoffer!)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With the xskak package you can define a variant of "NAG" comments to insert your double check:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{xskak}
\expandafter\def\csname $++\endcsname{\checksymbol\checksymbol}
\expandafter\def\csname $+\endcsname{\checksymbol}

\begin{document}
\newchessgame[setpieces={Kg1,Rg2,Bg4,kg8}]

\mainline{1. Be6 $++ \xskakcomment{! (doublecheck!)} Kh8}

\newchessgame[setpieces={Kg1,Rg2,Bg4,kg8}]
\mainline{1. Be6+ $+ \xskakcomment{ (doublecheck!)} Kh8}
\end{document}
```

[image]